# How to trigger click call from code in Safari

Tags: angular, file-io, safari, click

I need to trigger a file input control without showing the default file "Select" button. In Chrome, I am able to call `this.fileInput.nativeElement.click()` and trigger the file finder dialog open. However, in Safari 14.1.1, the file dialog does not get popped up.
The html snippet:

```
<input
  #fileInput
  type="file"
>
```

In Angular component .ts file:

```
@ViewChild("fileInput") fileInput: ElementRef;
...
activateFileInput() {
  this.fileInput.nativeElement.click()
}
```

Calling activateFileInput() method opens the file dialog in Chrome or Firefox, but not in Safari (I am testing with Safari 14.1.1).

Comment: Did you set `display: none` for input?

Comment: Yes, I did. Actually, I found the issue: I invoked activateFileInput() in the callback of a dialog.afterClosed(). In Safari, it seems the dialog close takes much longer than in Chrome, the fileInput element was not found in Safari while the dialog was closing. When changing the call to activateFileInput() into the callback of dialog.beforeClose() it works in both Chrome and Safari. Thank you @Haophamvan